# How to exclude specific Ip address while adding Iptables Reject Rule

Tags: iptables

I am trying to Add Reject Rule for Outgoing traffic but I want to exclude one specific Ip address so that I can ssh. I tried adding two different rules

1. sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d x.x.x.x/32 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
2. sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d x.x.x.x/22 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

I tried changing the order of rules but still I am unable to overide "Reject" Rule and ssh into x.x.x.x/32 server

Comment: you should give the whole ruleset, in case something else than just these two rules is at play: `iptables-save -c`.

Comment: Hi A.B, thanks for taking a look.. I tried saving iptables rule but that didn't help :(

Comment: You didn't get it: `iptables-save -c` 's output: your rules, should be provided in this question (by editing it) so people can help you with an answer.

Comment: 1. sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d x.x.x.x/32 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
2. sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d x.x.x.x/32 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
3. sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d x.x.x.x/29 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

I did it ... Thank you

Comment: Please add the output to the question in a code block, it is not readable from a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove previous broken rules, and try this (it worked for me):

```
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! -d x.x.x.x/32 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
```

This means that if the outgoing traffic is SSH (TCP 22) but not destined to x.x.x.x/32, drop the traffic.